# Choose masterpage base on request

Tags: custom-masterpage

Is it possible to set current request's masterpage based on query string, so that everybody will get default masterpage except one with *?masterpage=MyCustomMasterpage* in URL, who will get MyCustomMasterpage masterpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have [a blog post](http://mike-greene.com/2011/10/dynamic-master-page-logic/) on how to set master pages dynamically--that may also help you as it supports the post Alexander posted, though not as detailed.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own HttpModule. Read [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43377/SharePoint-Dynamically-Change-Master-Page) for more details.